# Accessing child.type.name in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using React Functional components throughout a Typescript application.

I'm trying to dynamically update some child components in another component, as below:

```
const memoizedIterateAndAddProps = useCallback(
    (kids: ReactNode) => {
      return React.Children.map(kids, (child) => {
        if (React.isValidElement(child)){
           console.log(child.type.name)
          }
      }
  }, [])
```

but typescript keeps complaining with `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string | JSXElementConstructor<any>'. Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)`

I get this is related to the fact that a child could just be a string, but I can't figure out a way of solving this that makes Typescript happy.

I'd be incredibly grateful for any help from anyone

Comment: What makes you think that `child.type` should have `name` property?

Comment: @captain-yossarian - `JSXElementConstructor` (the other half of the union with `string`) is a union of two `Function` types, and functions have a `name` property.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `child.type` is a union of `string` and `function`

Comment: @captain-yossarian - Right, that's what I was saying. (Specifically a union of `((props: P) => ReactElement<any, any> | null)` and `(new (props: P) => Component<P, any>)`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder maybe I missed something, but if you take a look at `ReactElement` type, you will see that property `type`  is a union of `string | JSXElementConstructor<any>`. Hence, `type` might be a `string` as well. It is not a union of two functions

Comment: @captain-yossarian - Right -- that's what I meant by *"`JSXElementConstructor` (the other half of the union with `string`)"*. I was answering your question about why the OP expected `name`. It comes from functions. All they have to do is strip out `string` from the union type. I think it was just a misunderstanding. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239041/discussion-between-captain-yossarian-and-t-j-crowder).

Answer (score 7):

> ...but I can't figure out a way of solving this that makes Typescript happy.

Check that it isn't a string:

```typescript
const memoizedIterateAndAddProps = useCallback(
    (kids: ReactNode) => {
        return React.Children.map(kids, (child) => {
            if (React.isValidElement(child) && typeof child.type !== "string") {
//                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
               console.log(child.type.name);
            }
        });
    }
);
```

(Or `&& "name" in child.type` would work too.)

You get a string for `type` when you do `<div/>` and such, so you have to filter out that case if you want to use `name`.

Answer (score 3):

```
import { isValidElement } from 'react'

if (isValidElement(child) && typeof child.type === 'function') {
  console.log(child.type.name) // safe access to name
}
```

Checks that:

- `child` is a `ReactElement`, and react elements have `type` property.
- `type` is a `function`, and functions have `name` property.

Answer (score 1):

`React.isValidElement` has this type signature:

```js
function isValidElement<P>(object: {} | null | undefined): object is ReactElement<P>;
```

Above typeguard, narrows `child` to be `ReactElement` which has this type signature:

```js
interface ReactElement<P = any, T extends string | JSXElementConstructor<any> = string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> {
        type: T;
        props: P;
        key: Key | null;
    }
```

As you might have noticed, `type` is a union of `string` and `JSXElementConstructor<any>`.

Hence, if you want to make sure that you have a deal with function, you should use custom typeguard:

```js
const isFunction=(data:any):data is (...args:any[])=>any => typeof data === 'function'
```

WHole code:

```js
import React, { useCallback, ReactNode } from 'react'
const isFunction = (data: any): data is (...args: any[]) => any => typeof data === 'function'

const App = () => {
  const memoizedIterateAndAddProps = useCallback(
    (kids: ReactNode) => {
      return React.Children.map(kids, (child) => {
        if (React.isValidElement(child) && isFunction(child.type)) {
          console.log(child.type.name)
        }
      }
  }, [])

  return null
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMIoA25ARugNbbLowByEAJknAL5wBmUEEHADkUVBmEAoNBAB2heMEIAxfLIzA5cALxwAFGxQwUALjgpZATwCUZw8bhL9AOlcooAc0JmLlgNoAutY6AHzmVqFwMJZgSBC8cPYoOtq6wrxqGnJS0nIKcACCYGA6%20sHaYTiScHAy8vAgSCAQwABeSGwAkjBIUEZIBbJsBWxsAAoCYISlRKQU1HR61TX6tMBs3ojiLOxI5ZXLK3BiMPhQsltMziQAFsDkbGKyziAoYHprG9h6aHcP%207hDkdHAk9IwMM4lAA1CjrACi5CaSFkMB%20fzYwQAZJjHCpMjBNLI0fc2M5orFrMEqsDgXVCBBEc5yBAPMSHmSYkhnLIUI1rECjlwBdxllxsIF%20csTmcLrJ8JRJFwgA)