# In Typescript, how can I tell which React functional component a variable is?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have a `CustomIcon` component that I use sometimes for my icons, and other times I use MUI's icons. I have a type with a variable defined as:

```
type ParentComponentProps = {
  icon: React.ReactElement<SvgIconProps> | typeof CustomIcon;
};
```

This way, I can call `ParentComponent` either this way:

```
<ParentComponent icon={<HomeIcon />}/>
```

or

```
<ParentComponent icon={<CustomIcon {...args}/>}/>
```

I want a way to determine from the value of `icon` if it's using the MUI icon or my `CustomIcon`. Within `ParentComponent`, I want to add arguments to the `icon` that gets passed in so that the consumers won't have to (e.g. I want to add `className` classes in addition to what the consumer might specify).

I've tried various ways to approach this, using `typeof`, `instanceof`, and `ReturnType` but they're all generally limited due to needing a value for the comparison rather than a type.

Is there a way to solve this using a condition, or does it need to be solved another way?

Comment: What would you like to do with the type of `icon`? Why can't you use `extends`?

Comment: I want to add arguments to the icon that gets passed in so that the consumers won't have to (e.g. I want to add `className` classes in addition to what the consumer might specify). What I add will change depending on if it's a MUI Icon or a `CustomIcon`. I've edited above to include this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

the type of created react component (in the format of `<Icon />`) is always be `JSX.Element`, if you need to some type checks, you should pass the component itself into the props

so the component props will be like belows, note that the name is changes to `Icon` because if you do `<icon />` inside, it will be consider you are try to use a native element call `icon`:

```js
type ParentComponentProps = {
  Icon: React.ComponentType<SvgIconProps> | typeof CustomIcon;
};
```

but usually I will let the props of `CustomIcon` (assume it is called `CustomIconProps`) compatible with `SvgIconProps`, and the types will be:

```js
type CustomIconProps = SvgIconProps & {
// ...
};

type ParentComponentProps = {
  Icon: React.ComponentType<SvgIconProps>;
};
```

which will be more clear.

and the usage:

```
<ParentComponent Icon={HomeIcon}/>
```

```
<ParentComponent Icon={CustomIcon}/>
```

if you need to pass `args` to `CustomIcon`:

```
<ParentComponent Icon={(props: CustomIconProps) => <CustomIcon {...props} {...args}/>}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want a way to determine from the value of icon

Where do you want to use that?

If you need it to determine another type, for example to type an `style` prop, you can do something like this:

```
      type SvgIcon = React.ReactElement<SvgIconProps>

      type ParentComponentProps<Icon extends  SvgIcon | typeof CustomIcon> = {
               icon: Icon;
               style: Icon extends SvgIcon ? Type1 : Type2
        
       };
```

Answer (score 0):

Even when you do:

```
<ParentComponent
  icon={<CustomIcon {...args}/>}
/>
```

...you are actually passing a `ReactElement` to the `icon` prop.

More generally, this is similar to the `children` prop, or any slot content prop. We generally type them as `ReactNode`, which also takes a `string`, `null`, or an array of `ReactNode`.

It is indeed possible to tell from a `ReactElement` from which Component it was built, typically by looking into its `type.name` property, but you need to guard it first, as described e.g. in [Accessing child.type.name in React Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69897913/accessing-child-type-name-in-react-typescript)

```
function ParentComponent({
    icon
}: {
    icon: React.ReactElement
}) {
    if (React.isValidElement(icon) && typeof icon.type === "function") {
        icon.type.name // Okay
    }
    return <></>
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoczAVwDsNgJa4BJNJgCgEo4BvcuILhEY1KMwA8APgkB6KRQC+ldrQDO8AMLUNuNkzgBeOBzA4wagFxwUtAJ49DUvgKEixkmfPLKqdBgYACihEtDCauJC0SGEc-EJwwKo+1vFCSUzWyOgwAHTZGACiADZIIDEwPjxpgsCYJgV5wGoAaijFwAAmJWUVHBm0PABkQ3AwdmBIEPUDueOTRobG+DT0MIy0+NWuCbWqcxNIubQo5XCysnAA8gDWKHY7cMoJ7uJw0nJSPipMGjZQAHM1EY+IoKOQJMFQuFIkwKolVIYau9tLoQPpmLxctiQkDFOcvvjvEA)